# How can I access my assembly version number in a partial trust environment (no FileIOPermission)

Tags: .net, reflection, cas, partial-trust

I'm trying to access the Version number of my assembly at runtime.

The code I'm using for that requires a FileIOPermission, which I don't want to grant (I'm in the Internet Zone)

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

Is there another way to access the version number which doesn't require elevation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite the same version number (It's the "AssemblyFileVersion" rather than the "AssemblyVersion" attribute) but you can use the following line of code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion
```

That returns a string.

If you're doing automated builds, then you have to remember to increment both numbers.

*Alternatively*

If you are doing this as a ClickOnce application, the version number is found in:

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you need the AssemblyVersion without FileIOPermission you will have to parse Assembly::FullName.